# laravel eloquent using when() with nested load()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Dear laravel community,

is there any way to use `when()` with a nested `load()`?

See this code:

```
public function getOrder($order, Request $request){
...
case 'transactions':
    //this will be loaded for all orders
    $order->load([
        'referralTransactions' => function ($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        },
    ])
    //when order is of currency typ0 load all these relations additionally
    ->when($order->currency_type == 0, function ($query) {
        $query->load([
            'someRelation1' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
            'someRelation2' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
        ]);
    })
    //when order is of currency 1 we load other relations additionally
    ->when($order->currency_type == 1, function ($query) {
        $query->load([
            'someOtherRelation' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
        ]);
    });
break;
```

Any idea how to get this work?
Is this supported in general?

It says `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::load()`

Comment: You can use load() in that context, because you have a query builder here, use ->with() instead. If you want to keep using ->load() you will need to remove the ->when() call and use an if statement instead

Answer (score 0):

First solution, use load on the $order :

```
public function getOrder($order, Request $request){
...
case 'transactions':
    //this will be loaded for all orders
    $order->load([
        'referralTransactions' => function ($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        },
    ]);
    //when order is of currency typ0 load all these relations additionally
    if($order->currency_type == 0) {
        $order->load([
            'someRelation1' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
            'someRelation2' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
        ]);
    }
    //when order is of currency 1 we load other relations additionally
    if($order->currency_type == 1) {
        $order->load([
            'someOtherRelation' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
        ]);
    }
break;
```

second solution, use ->with() instead :

```
public function getOrder($order, Request $request){
...
case 'transactions':
    //this will be loaded for all orders
    $order = $order->with([
        'referralTransactions' => function ($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        },
    ])
    //when order is of currency typ0 load all these relations additionally
    ->when($order->currency_type == 0, function ($query) {
        $query->with([
            'someRelation1' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
            'someRelation2' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
        ]);
    })
    //when order is of currency 1 we load other relations additionally
    ->when($order->currency_type == 1, function ($query) {
        $query->with([
            'someOtherRelation' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
        ]);
    })->first();
break;
```

i think the second option is better, it will make one query instead of 2

edit :

here a third solution, adapted from the first one :

```
public function getOrder($order, Request $request){
...
case 'transactions':
    //this will be loaded for all orders
    $load = [
        'referralTransactions' => function ($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        },
    ];
    
    
    //when order is of currency typ0 load all these relations additionally
    if($order->currency_type == 0) {
        $load = array_merge([
            'someRelation1' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
            'someRelation2' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
        ], $load);
    }
    //when order is of currency 1 we load other relations additionally
    if($order->currency_type == 1) {
        $load = array_merge([
            'someOtherRelation' => function ($query) {
                $query->withTrashed();
            },
        ], $load);
    }
    $order->load($load);
break;
```

you can do a single ->load() that way

Comment: only the first solution works, the second just don't fetch any data, only `referralTransactions` is loaded, none of the other relations.

Comment: Yes, because with the second solution you will need to call ->first() to make the request i think, i edited my response

Comment: Can you show an example please? I don't understand how I should call `first()` when using the `when()` statements.

Comment: I edited my response, you call first() at the end to make the request, you are making a new request with that solution, instead of just loading relations of an existing object. But since using load() avoid fetching order again perhaps its better to use load() than with()

Comment: Very strange, still there's only the `referralTransaction` loaded. I've included a `dd()` statement directly in the head of the template to dump the whole `order` object.

Comment: Well it's strange it works on my side, i guess if the first solution works for you, keep that one, you can even factor it to have only one load call